# CakePHP 1.3 $this -> save () doesn't execute a query

Tags: php, cakephp, save, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3 I'm trying to save some data to a MySQL database. The data doesn't come from a form, but to imitate it I put the data in the $this -> data array like this:

```
$this -> data = Array (
                         'User' => Array (
                                            'last_login' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                         )
                      );
```

This creates an array that looks exactly like the default Cake data array. So far so good.

Next, I call the following function:

```
if ($this -> User -> save ($this -> data))
{
   echo $this -> User -> id;
}
else
{
   echo 'Save failed';
}
```

It always comes up with 'Save failed', showing the data wasn't saved correctly. I tried to debug this in a variety of ways:

I checked whether a beforeSave or beforeValidate function existed in my User model or AppModel and whether these return true. (They did.)

I echoed `$this -> Session -> flash ()` in default.ctp. It doesn't say anything.

I echoed `$this -> element ('sql_dump')` in default.ctp. I don't see any sign of the query I expect, confirming my expectation of the query not executing instead of just failing.

From my controller I echoed `$this -> validationErrors`. It's empty so validation seems to be ok.

I tried to provide the correct index in my `$this -> data array` for the save, like this:

```
$this -> User -> save ($this -> data['User']);
```

I checked whether I loaded my User model via `$this -> loadModel ('User')` (I did).

Note that I try to do this in my AppController (that's why I loaded the model manually). More specifically: it's in the `beforeFilter ()` function in the AppController. This function is called in the `beforeFilter ()` function in every other Controller my application has (I checked this).

At the moment, I don't know what could cause this. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying the User id before you save, so CakePHP has no idea what row to save the date to. In effect, you're asking CakePHP to just save a date, without specifying where. I am away from my webdev box right now, but I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
if( ! isset( $this->User->id ) ) {
    $this->User->create();
}
$this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM));
```

See [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) for more information. BTW, if you want to do it the way you were originally doing it, I think this is the way:

```
if( ! isset( $this->User->id ) ) {
        $this->User->create();
        $myId = $this->User->getLastInsertID();
} else {
  $myId = $this->User->id;
}

$this -> data = Array (
      'User' => Array (
      'id' => $myId
      'last_login' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   )
);

if ($this -> User -> save ($this -> data))
{
   echo $this -> User -> id;
}
else
{
   echo 'Save failed';
}
```

Comment: I'm ashamed I forgot that, because right now I'm reading through that page for the third time today... Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. The query still doesn't show up in the query list :(

Comment: So, you tried something like this, then looked in the mysql table under the user and the last_login wasn't updated?
$this -> data = Array (
                         'User' => Array (  'id'=1,
                                            'last_login' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                         )
                      );

Comment: Since you are only saving one field, did you try the saveField method? $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM));

Comment: Peter Nore, you're my hero. saveField in combination with the (overlooked by me) User -> create () did exactly what I needed to be done! Could you maybe edit your first answer to include the updateField method so that the answer marked as solution includes a complete solution? :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to update your last_login

`$this->User->id`

`$this->User->saveField('last_login', date ('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`

or 
if you save all record then you have this type of array and you must have "id".

this "id" you get by session or anyway

`$this -> data = Array (
      'User' => Array (
      'id' => $myId
      'last_login' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   )
);`

`if ($this -> User -> save ($this -> data))
{
   echo $this -> User -> id;
}
else
{
   echo 'Save failed';
}`